# Special casing or over-riding Remove-Item so that rm -rf matches linux behavior

Tags: powershell

I'd like to special case `rm -r -fo` in powershell so that I can match the linux alias `rm -r -f`. Is it possible to setup aliases as such that override modifiers, so that both `rm -rf` and `rm -r -f` pass `-Force` instead of `Filter`? Clearly I could create  a function

Comment: The force switch is literally `-Force` on PowerShell

Comment: Yes I'm aware, and my question is if it's possible to alias this to `-f`

Comment: Since there would be two ambiguous switches to just `-f` I don't believe this is possible with the stock `Remove-Item` command but you could always use WSL with `bash -c "rm -rf"`

Comment: `rm -fo` would work

Comment: If you read my question I already remarked about `rm -fo`, again that's not what I am asking.